# Display all dates between two different dates using XSLT

Tags: datetime, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need a correct logic that works on XSLT 2.0 that display all dates between given two different dates. For example if

- Start date: `2022-10-01` (YYYY-MM-dd)
- End date: `2023-04-01`

I need display results like:
`2022-10-31, 2022-11-30, 2022-12-31, 2023-01-31 , 2023-02-28, 2023-03-31, 2023-04-30`

I figure out the date part, but I don't know how to increment month and year part exactly. When month reaches 12 (dec), it again should start from 1 (jan) and simultaneously increment current year count. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the number of days between the dates: `fn:days-from-duration((xs:date('2023-04-01') - xs:date('2022-10-01'))`

and then produce a sequence of 1 to the number of days in the duration, convert that number into an `xs:dayTimeDuration()` of days, and add those days to the start date:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="start" select="xs:date('2023-04-01')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="end" select="xs:date('2022-10-01')"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="(1 to fn:days-from-duration(($start - $end )) ) ! ($start + xs:dayTimeDuration('P'||.||'D') )"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```